# Multiple ListView on Button Click

Tags: android, android-listview

I wanted to create Mutiple ListView on Click of Button.Like as Show

-----ButtonClick---

ListView1(on first Click)

ListView2(on second Click)

ListView3(on third Click)

and so on...

i.e Different ListView on ButtonClick Above

Any Suggestion Aprreciated...Thks

Comment: Need to change the adapter and set that adapter to listview in button click event.

Comment: There are different approach in dealing with this problem. Have you ever tried anything? Share your code with us, so it's easier to help.

Comment: isn't this concept of expandable listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different activities for different List views. e.g On click of Button 1, you will be moved to activity 1 which has List view A; On click of Button 2, you will be moved to activity 2 which has List view B; On click of Button 3, you will be moved to activity 3 which has List view C, and so on...

```
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    on button 1 click,

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item, list1);
        yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter1);  
                    }
                });


 on button 2 click,

 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item, list2);
    yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter1);  
                }
            });


 on button 3 click,

 button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item, list3);
    yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter1);  
                }
            });
```

Comment: yes, it is very simple.... What u have to do here is in same adapter u have to change the array list (ur data which u want to show in listview).

Comment: perfect but it has to be on the same button

Comment: able to change the arraylist but it is just replacing the previous item.It is not getting me the Listview i have shown in my diagram in Ques?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39467/discussion-between-nit-and-anil-bhatiya)

Answer (score 0):

you can use count in this case like

static int a = 0;

and then on click of you button you can increases the value of that count and check

if(count%3 == 0)
{
/* 1st list view here */
}

if(count%3 == 1)
{
/* 2nd list view here */
}

if(count%3 == 2)
{
/* 3rd list view here */
}